# Erro Parse error: (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo onde só contém o seguinte código começando na primeira linha:

```
<?php
echo "01";
?>
```

Porém ao executar, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"01"'
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Como pode dar erro com esse comando se não tem nada antes ou depois? Então ajustei dessa forma:

```
<?php echo "01"; ?>
```

E finalmente funciona. Estou criando no Netbeans 8.2. Alguém sabe me informar o porque isso ocorre para caso aconteça nas outras páginas, eu saiba como corrigir, pois perdi um bom tempo tentando resolver isso e sinceramente não consegui entender. Quando dei um print, no Google aparece **HTTP error 500**

O arquivo está dentro do diretório:

**public_html/site/**

Porém tem um arquivo htaccess dentro da pasta raiz **public_html** que faz o direcionamento para o diretório **site/**

```
# Bloqueia acesso direto a pastas
Options All -Indexes

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.sitecliente.com.br/site

# Redirect index.php Requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Adiciona o www a frente do dominio
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seusite.com.br [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.seusite.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Erros personalizados
#ErrorDocument 401 /erros/falhaautorizacao.html
#ErrorDocument 404 /erros/naoencontrado.html
#ErrorDocument 403 /erros/acessonegado.html
#ErrorDocument 500 /erros/errointerno.html

# Melhorando o cache para maior velocidade
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=28800"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Tem algum arquivo htaccess?

Comment: Tem certeza que não havia nenhum caractere invisível na primeira versão do código? Porque ao copiar o seu código, aparece um [caractere invisível](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BB%BF%3C%3Fphp%0D%0Aecho+%2201%22%3B%0D%0A%3F%3E%EF%BB%BF) logo no início.

Comment: Aliás, aparecem 23 caracteres onde deveriam ter 19, se não contei errado.

Comment: @rray tem sim. Alterei meu post.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não tem, pois eu digitei o código.